# Can bootstrap adjustment for $p$-value in AR model be applied to distributed lag model?

Tags: bootstrap, multiple-comparisons, lags, distributed-lag

In Wang ["Multiple testing correction in time series: rolling window analysis with applications of GWAS methods"](https://digitalcommons.mtu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2636&context=etdr) (2022), the author mentioned that bootstrap minimum $p$-value can be applied on the residuals of fitted AR model (p. 26). Is it possible to apply it on a DLM with daily death count as dependent variable and temperature with 21 lags as independent variables?

The information about Bootstrap adjustment is as below:
[image]
In step 1, n window will 21 lags in my question;
$\hat{p} will be :$
[image]
The author applied the bootstrap adjustment to AR model instead of DLM, is it possible for me to apply the same technique to DLM?

The equation will be:
$$ 
Daily Death_t \sim \beta_0 + \beta_1 Temp_{t-1} + \dots + \beta_{21} Temp_{t-21} + u_t
$$
I would like to perform multiple corrections to all lagged variables of $Temp_{t-i}$.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? I cannot follow the question without reading the thesis that you refer to.

Comment: Sorry for causing inconvenience, I have added more details.